# Can we pass a message directly from seda:queue to direct:endpoint in camel?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-camel, integration

Using below configuration:

```
<camel:camelContext>
<camel:template id="camelProcessTemplate" />
    <camel:endpoint id="asyncEndpoint" uri="seda:asyncQueue" />
    <camel:endpoint id="calcWeightEndpoint" uri="direct:calculateWeightIn" />

 <camel:route id="route1">
  <camel:from ref="..." />
  <camel:to ref="asyncEndpoint" />
 </camel:route>

 <camel:route id="route2">
  <camel:from ref="asyncEndpoint" />
  <camel:to ref="calcWeightEndpoint" />
 </camel:route>

<camel:route id="route3">
 <camel:from ref="calcWeightEndpoint" />
 <camel:process ref="..." />
 <camel:to ref="..." />
</camel:route>

</camel:camelContext>
```

The message is entering into route2 but is not getting passed to route3.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `uri` attributes instead of the `ref` attributes in your `from`s and `to`s:

```
<camel:to uri="direct:calculateWeightIn" />
```

Also, it's possible that your processor in route3 is failing and not logging properly. Maybe add a `<camel:log />` step between the `from` and the `process`.

---

**EDIT 1:** OP updated the question to correct their code block.

Could you please add a `<camel:log />` between the `from` and the `process`, to verify whether the message is arriving in `route3`? The problem may be in your processor, as I said above.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, updated the question, I feel that's not the problem.

Comment: No use ref when you refer to the endpoints by the id. If you use uri, then you need to use the ref:id syntax, see: http://camel.apache.org/ref